# Return only rows from the joined table with the latest date

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, duplicates

By running the following query I realized that I have duplicates on the column `QueryExecutionId`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT qe.QueryExecutionid AS QueryExecutionId,
    wfi.workflowdefinitionid AS FlowId,
    qe.publishing_date AS [Date],
    c.typename AS [Type],
    c.name As Name
INTO #Send
FROM
    [QueryExecutions] qe  
    JOIN [Campaign] c ON qe.target_campaign_id = c.campaignid
    LEFT JOIN [WorkflowInstanceCampaignActivities] wfica ON wfica.queryexecutionresultid = qe.executionresultid
    LEFT JOIN [WorkflowInstances] wfi ON wfica.workflowinstanceid = wfi.workflowinstanceid
WHERE qe.[customer_idhash] IS NOT NULL;
```

E.g. When I test with one of these QueryExecutionIds, I can two results

```
select * from ##Send
where QueryExecutionId = 169237
```

We realized the reason is that these two rows have a different `FlowId` (second returned value in the first query). After discussing this issue, we decided to take the record with a `FlowId` that has the latest date. This date is a column called `lastexecutiontime` that sits in the third joined table `[WorkflowInstances]` which is also the table where FlowId comes from.

How do I only get unique values of `QueryExecutionId` with the latest value of `WorkflowInstances.lastexecution` time and remove the duplicates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a derived table with `first_value` partitioned by `workflowinstanceid` ordered by `lastexecutiontime desc`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT qe.QueryExecutionid AS QueryExecutionId,
    wfi.FlowId,
    qe.publishing_date AS [Date],
    c.typename AS [Type],
    c.name As Name
INTO #Send
FROM
    [QueryExecutions] qe  
    JOIN [Campaign] c ON qe.target_campaign_id = c.campaignid
    LEFT JOIN [WorkflowInstanceCampaignActivities] wfica ON wfica.queryexecutionresultid = qe.executionresultid
    LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT workflowinstanceid, FIRST_VALUE(workflowdefinitionid) OVER(PARTITION BY workflowinstanceid ORDER BY lastexecutiontime DESC) As FlowId
        FROM [WorkflowInstances]
    ) wfi ON wfica.workflowinstanceid = wfi.workflowinstanceid
WHERE qe.[customer_idhash] IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: I also wrote a similar alternative to your answer. Instead of `PARTITION BY` I used a simple `GROUP BY`. I don't know why I still get duplicate values for the exact same queryexecutionids.

Comment: I can't test because you didn't provide sample data. If you could edit your question to include it (as ddl+dml) and desired results, that would help getting a correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that your distinct query is pertaining to the selected variables, 
eg. Data 1 (QueryExecutionId = 169237 and typename = test 1) 
    Data 2 (QueryExecutionId = 169237 and typename = test 2) 
The above 2 data are considered as distinct

Try partition by and selection the [seq] = 1 (the below code are partition by their date)

```
SELECT *
    into #Send
    FROM
    (
           SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [QueryExecutionid] ORDER BY [Date] DESC) [Seq]  
           FROM
           (
                  SELECT    qe.QueryExecutionid AS QueryExecutionId,
                            wfi.FlowId,
                            qe.publishing_date AS [Date], --should not have any null values
                            qe.[customer_idhash]
                            c.typename AS [Type],
                            c.name As Name

                  FROM [QueryExecutions] qe  
                  JOIN [Campaign] c 
                  ON qe.target_campaign_id = c.campaignid
                  LEFT JOIN [WorkflowInstanceCampaignActivities] wfica 
                  ON wfica.queryexecutionresultid = qe.executionresultid
                  LEFT JOIN 
                    (
                        SELECT DISTINCT workflowinstanceid, FIRST_VALUE(workflowdefinitionid) OVER(PARTITION BY workflowinstanceid ORDER BY lastexecutiontime DESC) As FlowId
                        FROM [WorkflowInstances]
                    ) wfi ON wfica.workflowinstanceid = wfi.workflowinstanceid

           ) a
           WHERE [customer_idhash] IS NOT NULL
    ) b
    WHERE [Seq] = 1 
    ORDER BY [QueryExecutionid]
```